# cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk fails to install

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

[image]I'm just making a quick test on this plugin. I've created an empty apache cordova app, made the setup on firebase and installed the following plugin:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin

The build is successful but the app crashes on start.

**Logcat:**

*Process: com.commerce.miroir.mobile.companion, PID: 14220
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordova.MCInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing required properties: notificationCustomizationOptions*

Any ideas of what's missing?

*Using 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.6\bin\gradle*

My `config.xml` file looks like image below:

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're providing all necessary configuration values as specified in the documentation https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/README.md#installation.  Specifically, this error is due to `notification_small_icon` not being present in your `config.xml`

Comment: I have that line in the `config.xml` file but i've not any icon on `res\` folder. Is that the issue?

Comment: I've already managed to run this plugin without crashing my app. Problem was notification icon missing. However i now obtain a different error: `Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.commerce.miroir.mobile.companion. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

What I'm missing now?

Comment: Make sure you're following all of the instructions from the link in my answer.

Comment: Hi Seth, 
I've followed the installation steps on the guide. However i had to include two extra steps to make this work: SENDER_ID had to be included in `config.xml` otherwise the app fails. I had also to include the icon set on `platforms\android\app\src\main\res` as per your comments. Thank you. I think that the installation guide could be more clear in relation with these additional steps. I was able to make the plugin work now, but I'm obtaining the error above everytime i test on Firebase CM console by just sending an test notification. Is this expected?

Comment: Complete error log is:
`Unable to retrieve sender id.  Push messages will not work for Marketing Cloud.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.commerce.miroir.mobile.companion. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
 at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordova.MCSdkConfig.parseConfig(MCSdkConfig.java:115)
 at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordova.MCSdkConfig.prepareConfigBuilder(MCSdkConfig.java:60)
 
 ...`